# Comparing two dataframes of different length row by row and adding columns for each row with equal value

Tags: python, pandas, compare, dataframe

I have two dataframes of different length in python pandas like this:

```
df1:                                 df2:

      Column1  Column2 Column3            ColumnA ColumnB 
    0    1       a       r              0    1       a
    1    2       b       u              1    1       d
    2    3       c       k              2    1       e
    3    4       d       j              3    2       r
    4    5       e       f              4    2       w
                                        5    3       y 
                                        6    3       h
```

What I am trying to do now is comparing Column1 of df1 and ColumnA of df2. For each "hit", where a row in ColumnA in df2 has the same value as a row in Column1 in df1, I want to append a column to df1 with the vaule ColumnB of df2 has for the row where the "hit" was found, so that my result looks like this:

```
df1:

   Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4 Column5  Column6
0     1        a        r        a       d        e
1     2        b        u        r       w
2     3        c        k        y       h
3     4        d        j
4     5        e        f
```

What I have tried so far was:

```
for row in df1, df2:
   if df1[Column1] == df2[ColumnA]:
      print 'yey!'
```

which gave me an error saying I could not compare two dataframes of different length. So I tried:

```
for row in df1, df2:
    if def2[def2['ColumnA'].isin(def1['column1'])]:
        print 'lalala' 
    else:
        print 'Nope'
```

Which "works" in terms that I get an output, but I do not think it iterates over the rows and compares them, since it only prints 'lalala' two times. So I researched some more and found a way to iterate over each row of the dataframe, which is:

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    print row['Column1]
```

But I do not know how to use this to compare the columns of the two dataframes and get the output I desire.

Any help on how to do this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you to use DataFrame API which allows to operate with DF in terms of [*join*, *merge*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html), [*groupby*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html), etc. You can find my solution below:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': [1,2,3,4,5], 
    'Column2': ['a','b','c','d','e'], 
    'Column3': ['r','u','k','j','f']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3], 'ColumnB': ['a','d','e','r','w','y','h']})

dfs = pd.DataFrame({})
for name, group in df2.groupby('Column1'):
    buffer_df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': group['Column1'][:1]})
    i = 0
    for index, value in group['ColumnB'].iteritems():
        i += 1
        string = 'Column_' + str(i)
        buffer_df[string] = value

    dfs = dfs.append(buffer_df)

result = pd.merge(df1, dfs, how='left', on='Column1')
print(result)
```

The result is:

```
   Column1 Column2 Column3 Column_0 Column_1 Column_2
0        1       a       r        a        d        e
1        2       b       u        r        w      NaN
2        3       c       k        y        h      NaN
3        4       d       j      NaN      NaN      NaN
4        5       e       f      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

P.s. More details:

1) for df2 I produce *groups* by 'Column1'. The single *group* is a data frame. Example below:

```
   Column1 ColumnB
0        1       a
1        1       d
2        1       e
```

2) for each *group* I produce data frame *buffer_df*:

```
   Column1 Column_0 Column_1 Column_2
0        1        a        d        e
```

3) after that I create DF *dfs*:

```
   Column1 Column_0 Column_1 Column_2
0        1        a        d        e
3        2        r        w      NaN
5        3        y        h      NaN
```

4) in the end I execute left join for *df1* and *dfs* obtaining needed result.

2)* *buffer_df* is produced iteratively:

```
step0 (buffer_df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': group['Column1'][:1]})):
            Column1
         5       3

step1 (buffer_df['Column_0'] = group['ColumnB'][5]):      
            Column1 Column_0
         5       3       y

step2 (buffer_df['Column_1'] = group['ColumnB'][5]):      
            Column1 Column_0 Column_1
         5       3       y       h
```

Comment: Thank you, a very neat answer! However I notice that I do not quite understand what you're doing from buffer_df = .... until dfs = dfs.append(buffer_df). Could you explain what the code does? Thank you!

Comment: actually I think I get what the single lines of code do, but I do not get how they work together to create the output...

Comment: @sequence_hard check my answer again: new details are added. Have the process become clearer for you?

Comment: Yes, it is clear now, thank you for that very detailed answer. I was to braindead yesterday, that's the reason for my late answer. However when I try using the script for my actual data (which have a structure similar to the exemplary data, just with more columns in each df and mixed string/integer values), I get the following error: line 33, in <module>
    buffer_df[string] = group['Gene'][iter]
KeyError: 83                                                                                                             Any idea what the cause for that could be?

Comment: Since this: File "index.pyx", line 97, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:2679)
  File "index.pyx", line 105, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/index.c:2494)
  File "index.pyx", line 149, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3233)
  File "hashtable.pyx", line 381, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:7032)
  File "hashtable.pyx", line 387, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6973)
KeyError: 83 is also part of the error message, i guess something might be wrong with the indexing of my files...

Comment: @sequence_hard I've fixed code, it's more robust now. Try it. Let me know if something goes wrong. P.s. If it works fine plus my answer, please.

Comment: It works perfect now, thank you very much! I see how you used iteritems() there. I already upvoted your answer (Tell me if one can do more to send positive feedback on an answer:-)) Thanks again for your time and help!