# Create pandas df from difference between two dfs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, difference

**Set-up**

I have two pandas data frames `df1` and `df2`, each containing two columns with observations for id and its respective url,

```
| id | url |          | id | url | 
------------          ------------
| 1  | url |          | 2  | url |
| 2  | url |          | 4  | url |
| 3  | url |          | 3  | url |
| 4  | url |          | 5  | url |
                      | 6  | url |
```

Some observations are in both dfs, which is clear from the `id` column, e.g. observation `2` and it's `url` are in both dfs.

The positioning within the dfs of those 'double' observations does not necessarily have to be the same, e.g. observation `2` is in first row in `df1` and second in `df2`.

Lastly, the dfs do not necessarily have the same number of observations, e.g. `df1` has four observations while `df2` has five.

---

**Problem**

I want to elicit all unique observations in `df2` and insert them in a new df (`df3)`, i.e. I want to obtain,

```
| id | url |
------------
| 5  | url |
| 6  | url |
```

How do I go about?

I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36893675/7326714) but cannot get it to work for my two-column dataframes.

I've also tried [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28902170/7326714), but this gives me an empty `common` dataframe.

Comment: Are you after this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe? if so then it's a dupe

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot get that to work, see my question.

Comment: Please edit your post with your attempts from that question, stating that it doesn't work is not informative. I believe it would work but you need to prove it doesn't, also the answer from Greg should work, if it does then it's a dupe, if it doesn't then demonstrate this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly something like this: `df3 = df2[~df2.id.isin(df1.id.tolist())]`

Answer (score 1):

ID numbers make good index names:

```
df1.index = df1.id
df2.index = df2.id
```

Then use the very straightforward `index.difference`:

```
diff_index = df2.index.difference(df1.index)
df3 = df2.loc[diff_index]
```