# Python 3.6: Compare two large gzipped csv files & fetch difference records

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, gunzip

I have 2 gzipped csv files `IMFBOP2017_1.csv.gz` and `IMFBOP2017_2.csv.gz` with same columns in both file i.e `"Location, Indicator, Measure, Unit, Frequency, Date"`.

Total rows 60 millions+

I want to compare both file & display rows of `IMFBOP2017_1` that are not present in `IMFBOP2017_2`.

My plan is to import both files to dataframes , add an extra column "compare" to both dataframes and update it by all fields merge like

> Location|Indicator|Measure|Unit|Frequence|Date and do NOT IN operation.

I think this is a costly process, is there any simple solution for this?

Comment: you should try first, then ask what can be improved and provide code

Comment: Yes, it's a costly process. Are the rows in the files sorted in any way?

Comment: @ PM 2Ring, rows are not sorted.

Comment: Finding duplicated lines is a lot faster if the data is sorted. Perhaps you should use an external program to sort the data, like the *nix `sort` utility, which can easily sort files that are too big to fit into RAM. Once you have sorted data you can easily process it without reading it all into RAM: you just need to read row one row at a time from each file, and you can find the desired lines using a process similar to merging two lists. I don't know Pandas, so I don't know if Panda provides a function for this, but it's easy enough to write in pure Python.

Comment: @PM 2Ring, thanks for suggestion, will apply this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas can read gzipped data files with the ordinary `pandas.read_csv()`. How to do a diff between two dataframes is described in [Pandas: Diff of two Dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36891977/pandas-diff-of-two-dataframes) .

Comment: I refered link given above, its working... thanks a lot.